# how to scan with out our application will started in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to scan all the available wifi in background service.after that i need to check that particular SSID ID will be match i have to send some message to to user this will be happen in with out my activity will be started .any one guide me how to scan wifi in background service.

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            final String action = intent.getAction();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String name = prefs.getString("wifiname",null);

            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION) ||
                    action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED,
                        false)) {
                    if(context != null){
                        IntentFilter intentFil = new IntentFilter(); 
                        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        intentFil.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
                        wifi.startScan();
                        List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();

                        wifi.getScanResults();
                        if(wifi.startScan() == true){
                            for(int i = 0;i<configs.size();i++)
                        {
            if (configs.get(i).SSID.equals("\"" + name+"\"")){
                Toast.makeText(context,
                 name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                           
         }
```

Comment: @Lalit Poptani this is my current code i can't get scanned result here.guide me where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you write all the required permission in the manifest ?

Comment: @LalitPoptani ya i put all the permissions